# Probabilities regarding $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of sequence of independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

**Exercise :**

> Let $X_n, n=1,2,3,\dots$ be a sequence of independent continuous random variables. It's also given that all of $X_n$ have the same probability density function $f(x)$, for which it is $f(x) > 0 \space \forall \space x \in \mathbb R$. For a given real number $b$, consider the following events : 
>   $$A=\lim \sup_n \{X_n >b\}, \space B=\lim \inf_n \{X_n>b\}$$
>   $$G = \lim \sup_n \{X_n \leq b\}, \space D = \lim \inf_n\{X_n\leq b\}$$
>   Explain with simple words what each of the events above means and calculate their probabilities of happening.

**Discussion :**

It seems something that may have to do like ***Borrel - Cantelli*** Theorems, but I'm not even close to sure on how to proceed and make conclusions. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a past exam problem.

Comment: Can you write out the definition of $\limsup$/$\liminf$ of a sequence of sets?

Comment: What is the meaning of the expressions inside { }?  Is it a probability or something else?

Comment: It is an event, I think ;)

Comment: @herbsteinberg Events obviously. Read the whole question please, it is clearly stated that they pose random variables.